# How to avoid busy spinning in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I have a multi-threaded application where a thread sends a message to another thread. The waiting thread polls for the message and reacts (locks are handled). Like this:

Waiting thread code:

```
while(true)
{
  if(helloArrived())
    System.out.println("Got hello");
  if(byeArrived())
    System.out.println("Got bye");
  if(stopArrived())
    break;
}
```

I want to avoid this cpu hogging technique and use something else instead. Any ideas?

Edit: The actual code is below:

```
BlockingQueue<Mail> killMeMailbox = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Mail>();
BlockingQueue<Mail> messageMailbox = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Mail>();

public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(killMeMailbox.size() > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(messageMailbox.size() > 0)
            {
              System.out.println(messageMailbox.poll());
            }
        }
     }

public void receiveMail(Mail mail)
    {
        //kill
        if(mail.from == -1)
        {
            killMeMailbox.add(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //other
            try
            {
                messageMailbox.put(mail);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: You need a message queue. You can use BlockingQueue, so waiting thread will be blocked until message arrived.

Comment: I'm actually using that data structure. But I'm checking the size in the functions and clearing it as a handle them. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to avoid this is to use the wait/notify mechanism implemented by `java.lang.Object`, or one of the higher level concurrency mechanisms provided by the Java class libraries:

- [semaphores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html),
- [latches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)  / [cyclic barriers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html),
- blocking queues; e.g. the classes that implemented the [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface.

(Pick the mechanism that is the best match for what your specific use-case ...)

---

Using `Thread.sleep` is not a good solution.  While you reduce CPU load (compared with a polling loop), the flip-side is that you reduce responsiveness.

---

> I'm using a BlockingQueue now. But maybe I'm doing it incorrectly. I just added the actually code above. Do you see my problem?

Yea.  You are using the queue in a way that is designed to *avoid* blocking.  That's the wrong approach.  You should use `take()` (which will block until an entry becomes available) instead of `poll()`, and get rid of the code that tests the queue size.

Your "killMeMailbox" stuff seems to be designed to allow you to stop waiting for mail.  You should be able to implement that using `Thread.interrupt`.  (An interrupt will unblock a `take()` call ...)

Comment: I would sugest mentioning `LockSupport` instead of wait/notify. It is a 1-for-1 replacement for wait/notify, but doesn't suffer from race conditions.

Comment: I'm using a BlockingQueue now. But maybe I'm doing it incorrectly. I just added the actually code above. Do you see my problem?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I hear what you say, but I'm not familiar with it.  May I suggest that you add your own answer that explains how to use it.

Comment: Perfect! Take() is what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Those mechanism are too low-level anyway so there's no point writing a whole answer here just for that. But since wait/notify is effectively deprecated (*discouraged* is the term), I would refrain from mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). You should never do that because it wastes CPU cycles. A thread or process waiting for some event should be in [blocked state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state#Blocked_.28Waiting.29). Here are possible ways to achieve this:

- Use [Semaphores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)
- Use synchronized methods with [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)/[notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--)
- For specifically exchanging messages between threads, using [BlockingQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) may be the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you can reformulate your problem in terms of task-executor then consider using a [SingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29). If you need something more exotic - either [a concurrent queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or even [wait()/notify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to put some Thread.sleep to avoid executing the while loop constantly? It will liberate CPU for your other threads and avoid hogs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: While using `sleep` may work for some cases, using `notifyAll()/wait()` is better for reasons of responsiveness.

Comment: Then just put a small time in sleep or use another data structure. I think that there are some structures like BlockingQueue that allow the thread to wait until something is in the queue